# JSON Processing Using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to download a json file, save the file, and iterate through the json file in order to extract all information and save it is variables. I'm then going to format a message in csv format to send the data to another system. My problem is the json data. It appears to be a dictionary within a list and I'm not sure how to process it.

Here's the json:

```
[ {
  "ipAddress" : "",
  "feedDescription" : "Botted Node Feed",
  "bnFeedVersion" : "1.1.4",
  "generatedTs" : "2013-08-01 12:00:10.360+0000",
  "count" : 642903,
  "firstDiscoveredTs" : "2013-07-21 19:07:20.627+0000",
  "lastDiscoveredTs" : "2013-08-01 00:34:41.052+0000",
  "threatType" : "BN",
  "confidence" : 82,
  "discoveryMethod" : "spamtrap",
  "indicator" : true,
  "supportingData" : {
    "behavior" : "spamming",
    "botnetName" : null,
    "spamtrapData" : {
      "uniqueSubjectCount" : 88
    },
    "p2pData" : {
      "connect" : null,
      "port" : null
    }
  }
}, {
  "ipAddress" : "",
  "feedDescription" : "Botted Node Feed",
  "bnFeedVersion" : "1.1.4",
  "generatedTs" : "2013-08-01 12:00:10.360+0000",
  "count" : 28,
  "firstDiscoveredTs" : "2013-07-19 03:19:08.622+0000",
  "lastDiscoveredTs" : "2013-08-01 01:44:04.009+0000",
  "threatType" : "BN",
  "confidence" : 40,
  "discoveryMethod" : "spamtrap",
  "indicator" : true,
  "supportingData" : {
    "behavior" : "spamming",
    "botnetName" : null,
     "spamtrapData" : {
      "uniqueSubjectCount" : 9
    },
    "p2pData" : {
      "connect" : null,
      "port" : null
    }
  }
}, {
  "ipAddress" : "",
  "feedDescription" : "Botted Node Feed",
  "bnFeedVersion" : "1.1.4",
  "generatedTs" : "2013-08-01 12:00:10.360+0000",
  "count" : 160949,
  "firstDiscoveredTs" : "2013-07-16 18:52:33.881+0000",
  "lastDiscoveredTs" : "2013-08-01 03:14:59.452+0000",
  "threatType" : "BN",
  "confidence" : 82,
   "discoveryMethod" : "spamtrap",
  "indicator" : true,
  "supportingData" : {
    "behavior" : "spamming",
    "botnetName" : null,
    "spamtrapData" : {
      "uniqueSubjectCount" : 3
    },
     "p2pData" : {
      "connect" : null,
       "port" : null
    }
  }
 } ]
```

My code:

```
download = 'https:URL.BNfeed20130801.json'

request = requests.get(download, verify=False)
out  = open(fileName, 'w')
for row in request:
    if row.strip():
         for column in row:
                 out.write(column)
    else:
        continue
out.close()
time.sleep(4)
jsonRequest = request.json()

for item in jsonRequest:
     print jsonRequest[0]['ipAddress']
     print jsonRequest[item]['ipAddress'] --I also tried this
```

When I do the above it just prints the same IP over and over again.  I've put in the print statement for testing purposes only.  Once I figure out to to access the different elements of the JSON I will store it in variables and then use these variables accordingly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm using Python 2.6 on Linux.

Comment: `item` isn't an index; it's a dict from the list of dicts.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically iterating over list of dicts, try just `item['ipAddress']`.

Comment: I tried that as you suggested and I get:                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cyveillance.py", line 53, in <module>
    print jsonRequest['ipAddress']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Use `print item['ipAddress']` instead of `print jsonRequest['ipAddress']`.

Comment: @user2697611 why are you using `print jsonRequest['ipAddress']`? I've suggested to try `print item['ipAddress']`.

Comment: I misunderstood, using `for item in jsonRequest:
    print item['ipAddress']`
appears to be working

Answer (score 2):

alecxe's answer tells you how to fix this, but let me try to explain what's wrong with the original code.

---

It may be easier to understand with a simpler example, once you can run through an [interactive visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+=+%5B%27a%27,+%27b%27,+%27c%27%5D%0A%0Afor+item+in+a%3a%0A++++print+a%5B0%5D%0A&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

When you do this:

```
for item in a:
```

`item` will be `'a'` the first time through, then `'b'`, then `'c'`.

But if you do this:

```
for item in a:
    print a[0]
```

… you're completely ignoring `item`. It's just going to print `a` 3 times, because each time you go through the loop, you're just asking for `a[0]`—that is, the first thing in `a`.

And if you do this:

```
for item in a:
    print a[item]
```

… it's going to raise an exception, because you're asking for the `'a'`th thing in the list, which is nonsense.

But in this code:

```
for item in a:
    print item
```

… you'll print `'a'`, then `'b'`, then `'c'`, which is exactly what you want.

You could also do this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    print a[index]
```

… but that's silly. If you *need* the index, use `enumerate`, but if you just need the item itself… you've already got it.

---

So, back to your real code:

```
for item in jsonRequest:
     print jsonRequest[0]['ipAddress']
```

Again, you're ignoring `item` and asking for `jsonRequest[0]` each time.

And in this code:

```
for item in jsonRequest:
    print jsonRequest[item]['ipAddress'] --I also tried this
```

… you're asking for the `{complicated dictionary}`th thing in `jsonRequest`, which is again nonsense.

But in this code:

```
for item in jsonRequest:
    print item['ipAddress']
```

You're using each item, just as in the simple example.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation.  That makes a lot of sense.  How then do I go about access the directories within the directories?  I was trying to do this `behavior = item['supportingData']['behavior']` but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @user2697611: That _should_ work. When I change the line to `print item['supportingData']['behavior'] and use your sample JSON instead of pulling stuff down with `requests`, it prints `spamming` three times in a row, just as it should. If it's not working for you,  there's something wrong in code we can't see. You should probably accept alecxe's answer, then create a new question, with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for the new problem.

Comment: I actually tried it again and it seems to be working now.  I'm not sure what went wrong the first time.  Thanks for your comments.  I appreciate everyone's help.